# How can I move a folder from one directory to another in Windows command line?

Tags: windows, command-line, file-io

I need to a folder into the ProgramData directory. Is there a way I can see it as unhidden?

If not, what's the command to move one folder (name_of_folder) into another (c:\ProgramData) in Windows Vista?

Thanks.

Comment: You also ask "Is there a way I can see it as unhidden?" suppose it is c:\test\mydir  and has the hidden attribute set, then the command attrib -h c:\test\mydir   <-- will make that directory unhidden.  (folders and directories are the same thing they just might've started calling them folders around hmm, maybe win9x time I guess. To be more end user friendly)

Answer (score 32):

just open cmd.exe (Start -> write `cmd.exe` -> press `Enter`) and then type:

```
move "<source_dir>" "<destination_dir>"
```

where `<source_dir>` is the source directory path and `<destination_dir>` is the destination directory path. The quotation marks (`"`) are needed if the filepath(s) contain spaces.

Comment: If the folder names have spaces you'll need some quotation marks round each of the folder names.

Comment: Note that this does not show the progress, so if you're moving large folders, and want to see the progress, you'll have to use another tool.

Answer (score 4):

In CMD, enter:

```
move myFolder c:\ProgramData
```

Answer (score 0):

If you haven’t enogh user rights you can call the cmd.exe this way, too.

Click **Start** -> enter **cmd** in the input field

then hold the keys **STRG** plus **SHIFT** and hit **ENTER** too.

Now the run as admin dialog pops up ;)

Now `move name_of_folder c:\ProgramData` has power.

P.S. STRG is the German name for CTRL key.